# Code Level Transport Layer Protection

Tags: android, security

I am developing a tool  which scans android apps and shows the vulnerabilites found in it.I am stuck at one of OWASP vulnerability i.e **Insufficient Transport layer protection**. I am not able to find vulnerable code to create a pattern so that i can cross check it with any app. Please if you have any vulnerable code related to this vulnerability please tell me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are you doing static or dynamic analysis?

Comment: i am doing static analysis

Comment: Don't the android APIs usually make sure that when you do https, you do it with CN validation? Of course, sometimes "sufficient protection" means that you hardcode the cert so that normal CAs can't MITM you, but that depends on context, so you won't be able to check automatically for it.

Comment: Are you going to open-source the tool? If so, would you mind posting a link to your project here?

Comment: Sorry but that tool won't be open. It will be only for the firm.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have to check is, wether encryption is used for operations on the network.

For example: Is SSL/TLS enabled for Login-Requests? Is there any other sensitive information which is transferred in clear-text over the network? Is SSL configured in a secure way (e.g. no SSLv2)? and so on.

You can find a list on https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Transport_Layer_Protection_Cheat_Sheet what you have to consider while preventing this specific vulnerability.

However I think it's pretty hard to check if something isn't there...

I am not familiar with Android programming but I would look for any unencrypted socket creation or request, as this possibly is this kind of vulnerability.

Good luck ;-)